# Проверка на наличие объекта javascript

Tags: javascript

После `ajax` запроса `function(data)` проверяю наличие нужного объекта.

```
..., function(data)
{
    if (typeof(data.ads.photo) == "undefined")
        {
           console.log ('есть фото');
        }
    else
       {
          console.log ('нет фото');
       }
}
```

В чём проблема.
Такая проверка не заходит ни в if ни в else

Но если поставить проверку:

```
if (typeof(data.ads) == "undefined")
```

тогда показывать наличие или отсутствие. Что может быть не так?

Comment: "undefined" - не значение, а его отсутствие.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Без контекста сложно понять где вы это вызываете, но тут 2 варианта, либо от сервера приходит `data` в которой нет свойства `ads`, либо вы делаете эту проверку вне ajax и инициализируете `data` тоже вне, из-за этого проверка срабатывает раньше чем приходит ответ и опять же в `data` нет свойства `ads`

Comment: проверка проходит внутри функции callback, и там 2 варианта: нет ads.photo или есть. Так вот при проверке на ads при наличии ads.photo проверка успешна, при проверке на ads.photo при наличии ads.photo - вообще не проверяется (ни true ни false). Пока не разобрался почему так.

Comment: Звучит как магия ... приходит в голову, что photo может быть неправильно написано или типа того ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как `data.ads` неопределено, попытка обращения к `data.ads.photo` вызывает исключение, прерывающее исполнение кода.

```
if (!data || !data.ads || !data.ads.photo)
{
   console.log ('нет фото');
}
else
{
   console.log ('есть фото');
}
```

Comment: судя по тому, что проверяется работоспособность через `console.log()` думаю он бы заметил красную надпись.

Comment: @MedvedevDev "Это - вряд ли." т. Сухов, "Белое солнце пустыни"

Comment: спасибо. понял.

Comment: Хотя раньше не сталкивался с такой проверкой, не думал что проверка обьекта не существующего обьекта прерывает код, а не показывает false (else)

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии Проверка здесь - вторична. Причина ошибки - обращение к свойству несуществующего объекта.

Answer (score 3):

Причина названа в ответе @Igor, я лишь предложу более изящное решение:

```
..., function(data) {
  let photo, something; 
  try {
    photo = data.ads.photo; 
    something = data.ads.something;  // получение еще каких-либо данных из полей data
  } catch (err) {
    console.log ('опаньки... ' + err.message);
    return; 
  }
  ... // делаем что-то с photo и прочими значениями из data. Если код здесь тоже небезопасен, то его можно перенести в тело try
}
```

```js
var rslt = document.getElementById('result'), 
    btns = document.querySelectorAll('.test-btn'); 
for (let btn of btns)
  btn.addEventListener('click', fetchData); 

function fetchData(e) {
  console.clear(); 
  rslt.textContent = '\tПолучение данных... '; 
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/get').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
    let ip, ua, notExists; 
    try {
      ip = data.origin; 
      ua = data.headers['User-Agent']; 
      if (e.target.id === 'test-two')
        notExists = data.noObject.noValue; // тут будет ошибка, и выполнение перейдет в catch 
      rslt.textContent += `OK\n IP:${ip}\n UA:${ua}\n`; 
    } catch (err) {
      rslt.textContent += 'ошибка!\n'; 
      console.log(err.stack); 
    }
    rslt.textContent += '\tЗавершено.';  // выполняется вне зависимости от ошибок в try
  }); 
}
```

```css
#result {
  height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; 
  font: 14px monospace; white-space: pre-wrap;
  background-color: #222; color: #4d4;
}
```

```html
<button id="test-one" class="test-btn">Обычный тест</button>
<button id="test-two" class="test-btn">Тест с ошибкой</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```