# Как правильно проверить существование вложенного свойства JS?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно проверять вложенные свойства объектов на наличие, которых пока нет?

```js
let obj = {};

if (obj.prop.subprop) {
  console.log('ok');
}

obj = { 
  prop : "one",
  prop : "two",
  prop : {
    subprop : "subone"
         }
}
```

Comment: Только вот с условием "правильно", получается какая-то муть/неоднозначность: вроде бы не существует каких-либо каноничных правил выполнения подобных проверок. Чем обусловлена такая формулировка вoпроса? (Какие именно критерии у правильности, или неправильности? Есть ли пример неправильного, с уточнением что именно не устраивает в нем?)

Comment: Вот еще (напоминаю о старом вoпросе): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/814308/288409 - там другие способы проверок: либо OR-чейнинг, либо обработка ошибки в `try..catch`. Все это тоже вполне допустимо/применимо.

Answer (score 2):

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
let obj = {};

console.log(obj.prop?.subprop);
if (obj.prop?.subprop) {
  console.log('ok');
} else {
  console.log('not ok');
}

obj = {
  prop: {
    subprop: "subone"
  },
}

console.log(obj.prop?.subprop);
if (obj.prop?.subprop) {
  console.log('ok');
} else {
  console.log('not ok');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А есть ли где-то документация на такой синтаксис? Не смог найти.

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining